# How to create workflow to move document from site to its subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I need suggestion on share point workflow development.
Currently I am working on Share Point 2013. I have root site and its sub-sites.

```
Following is the challenge:
1. I have to move document from "Document Library" of root site to one of its sub-site using share point workflow.
2. Move document from sub-site to sub-site of root site.
```

I am not sure whether I should use "List workflow" or "Site workflow" as I am new in Share point.
I am using share point designer 2013 to develop workflow.
I search a lot on google but no luck on this.

Please provide yours valuable suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configuring SharePoint Content Organizer to route documents to a separate site collection and see the link also which helps you
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2011/06/27/configuring-sharepoint-content-organizer-to-route-documents-to-a-separate-site-collection.aspx